# docker retrieving env data in index.js and server.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, docker-compose

I have:

- index.js - opens on localhost:3000
- server.js - opens on localhost:5000

I make a connection between those two via socket.io like:
localhost:3000 <==> localhost:5000 - works fine

I retrieve MONGO_USER from docker-compose file in index.js - it works great so far.

Then I'm trying to retrieve MONGO_USER for server.js from docker-compose (using same piece of code), and thats where I become **undefined** as result, although it works fine for index.js.

I think something is messed up in docker part of the app, but i'm not sure

I also tried to use data I needed (manually, without getting it from docker-compose) and use it on mongodb connection, but I got:

```
MongooseServerSelectionError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mongo
```

and it looks to me like I have no access to mongo from server.js (although the socket connection between index.js and server.js works fine, and index.js has access to mongo)

docker-compose file:

```
version: "3"
services:
  test-app:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        NODE_ENV: development
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - /app/node_modules
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
      - MONGO_USER=test_admin
      - MONGO_PASSWORD=9293
    command: npm run dev
  mongo:
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=test_admin
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=9293
  mailhog:
    image: mailhog/mailhog
    logging:
      driver: 'none'  # disable saving logs
    ports:
      - 1025:1025 # smtp server
      - 8025:8025 # web ui
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon index.js && nodemon server.js",
    "dev": "nodemon index.js && nodemon server.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@socket.io/mongo-adapter": "^0.2.1",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.6",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "mongodb": "^4.6.0",
    "mongoose": "^6.3.2",
    "nodemailer": "^6.7.5",
    "socket.io": "^4.5.1",
    "ws": "^8.6.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.16"
  }
}
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:15
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install --only=production

ARG NODE_ENV
RUN if [ "$NODE_ENV" = "development" ]; \
        then npm install; \
        else npm install --only=production; \
        fi

COPY . ./
ENV PORT 3000
EXPOSE $PORT
CMD ["node", "index.js"]
```